# WPF Multiple ContentPresenters same content - Only 1 is populated

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

Here's an extremely basic example of what I'm trying to do but does not work:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Grid x:Key="MyYellowEllipse">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Yellow" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Key="MyBlueEllipse">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyYellowEllipse}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyBlueEllipse}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyYellowEllipse}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyBlueEllipse}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyYellowEllipse}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyBlueEllipse}" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Example Output]

For some reason when I do this, only the last two are populated (though space is left for the other). I would expect to be able to reuse the same content in multiple content presenters.

Why can't I do this, and more importantly, how should I be doing this instead if I want to achieve this.

I've built a bunch of custom glyphs using Path and Polygon objects in grids in a resource dictionary and I'd like to display them in multiple places in my app but they're only showing up in one usage (just like my example).  I thought ContentPresenter was meant for this.

**EDIT: It's a solution**

@emoacht pointed out in the comments that adding `x:Shared="False"` to the Grid in the resource definitions will fix the problem.  I'm going to use this solution for now.

For my own edification; however, I'd love if someone could explain to me A.) Why that's needed and B.) What the more appropriate solution to reusing a `<Grid>` with a bunch of `<Polygon>`s in it would be.

Comment: Adding `x:Shared="False"` to a Grid in Resources will make Ellipse visible in each ContentPresenter. But we don't usualy use ContentPresenter in such strange manner.

Comment: If i had a glyph in a resource dictionary that was a grid of paths, how would you recommend displaying that in multiple places without using a contentPresenter?

Comment: The straightforward way is defining a Style for Ellipse in Resources and replacing ContentPresenter with Ellipse to which the Style apply.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't quite work in my actual use case, cause sometimes the "glyph" is a grid with two paths in it, and in other cases it's a grid with one ellipse and a polygon and i need to dynamically decide which "glyph" to use by binding to a ViewModel field which looks up the resource by name.

Comment: A visual tree cannot be attached to multiple parents simultaneously, so only the two last content presenters end up rendering your two grids. I.e. by reusing the same resource over and over, you detach it from the old parent and attach to the new. In contrast, setting `x:Shared="False"` forces the resource dictionary to generate a copy of the resource each time it is referenced.

Comment: @AceGambit If so, define a Style for `ContentControl` or `Control` and use it. Or you can place multiple shapes in a `Path` by CombinedGeometry.

Answer (score 1):

> @emoacht pointed out in the comments that adding `x:Shared="False"` to the `Grid` in the resource definitions will fix the problem. I'm going to use this solution for now. For my own edification; however, I'd love if someone could explain to me

> A.) Why that's needed

Because the default resource-retrieval behavior in WPF is to share an instance of a XAML resource for all requests. You can read more about this in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xshared-attribute?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

> and B.) What the more appropriate solution to reusing a `<Grid>` with a bunch of s in it would be.

You could for an example define `MyYellowEllipse` and `MyBlueEllipse` as a custom types:

```
public class MyYellowEllipse : Grid
{
    public MyYellowEllipse()
    {
        Children.Add(new Ellipse() { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Yellow });
    }
}

public class MyBlueEllipse : Grid
{
    public MyBlueEllipse()
    {
        Children.Add(new Ellipse() { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Blue });
    }
}
```

...and use them in your XAML markup like this without involving any resources:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyYellowEllipse />
    <local:MyBlueEllipse />
    <local:MyYellowEllipse />
    <local:MyBlueEllipse />
    <local:MyYellowEllipse />
    <local:MyBlueEllipse />
</StackPanel>
```

You could obviously also create a base class called `MyEllipse` or something for code-sharing reasons but you get the point.

Comment: Ew.  I get why this works, but for some unknown reason my brain wants my glyphs to be in xaml, not C#.  I can't explain why this is. I appreciate the doc link for the Shared explanation.  For now I'm using that approach, but I'm gonna see if I can finagle a ControlTemplate for Grids and just define grids in my code that use specific ControlTemplates